# How can I extract response from json array in Karate

Tags: json, response, karate, jsonpath

I am trying to extract `response[0].otpValue` but it does not work

I have tried to:

```
get[0] response.id
response[0].otpValue
```

```
{
    "errorCode": null,
    "response": [
        {
            "createdTimestamp": 1557314537720,
            "lastUpdatedTimestamp": 1557314537720,
            "createdBy": null,
            "lastUpdatedBy": null,         
            "otpValue": "5346",
            "expiryTimestamp": 1556807308797,
            "validNow": false,
            "sessionUserId": null
        }
    ],
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "errorMessage": null
}
```

I am looking to get otpValue from above json response

```
* def firstOtp = response[0].id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* def answer = { "errorCode": null, "response": [ { "createdTimestamp": 1557314537720, "lastUpdatedTimestamp": 1557314537720, "createdBy": null, "lastUpdatedBy": null, "otpValue": "5346", "expiryTimestamp": 1556807308797, "validNow": false, "sessionUserId": null } ], "status": "SUCCESS", "errorMessage": null }
* def firstOtp = answer.response[0].otpValue
* match firstOtp == "5346"
```